# iOS Expected identifier problem when changed open url method to new one

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I don't understand why I got this error (see attached screen).

[image]

I have changed old open url to new one

```
 case AVAuthorizationStatusDenied:
    {
      [[[[[[ [ [ [UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {if (success) {NSLog(@"Opened url");}}
                    ] ] ]]]]]];
      break;
    }
    default:
      break;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why all the [[[[ ...
try this:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {if (success) {NSLog(@"Opened url");}}
     ];
```